# Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are: system-images;android-21;default;x86_64 null

Tags: flutter, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, android-emulator, avd-manager

I am trying to create an Android emulator for my VS Code on Ubuntu 2022LTS. I have installed `platform_tools`, `build_tools`and installed proper image, all located in `sdk_manager` directory. It seems the following command should work but I don't know why do I get the error:

`avdmanager create avd -n AndroidDevice01 -k “system-images;android-21;default;x86_64" --device "Pixel_6”`

The error:

`[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...        Error: Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are: system-images;android-21;default;x86_64 null android-21: command not found Command 'default' not found, did you mean: command 'defaults' from deb gnustep-base-runtime (1.28.0-4build1) Try: sudo apt install <deb name> x86_64 --device Pixel_6”: command not found`

This is the `flutter doctor` command result:

```
> 
> Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
> Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS 5.15.0-56-generic,
> locale en_US.UTF-8)
> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
> Chrome - develop for the web
> Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
> Android Studio (not installed)
> VS Code (version 1.73.1)
> Connected device (2 available)
> HTTP Host Availability
> 
> Doctor found issues in 1 category.
> 
>
```

I searched through the internet and tried different commands but they didn't work as well!